# Starting and dismissing progressDialog from Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have an android application with this structure:

Activity A,B,C,
Service S

When I'm on the Activity C I open a dialog in which I insert some data. When the Ok button is pressed, I do this two operation:

1. Start a service
2. call a Intent for starting Activity A (that is the main activity)

Until the service does not provide all the necessary data the actvity A will show inconsistent data and all button will be disabled. I would that until the data are not available, I progress bar is displayed.

So the problem is that I need to start my progressDialog from a dialog in the Activity C, I need to "link" the dialog to main activity (A) and than dismiss this progressDialog from Service.

How can I perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LocalBroadcastManager register it in onStart and unregister in onPause in Activitys you want communicate with the service. In service compute the expensive operation and sendBroadcast when the job finishes.
In Activity C show the progress dialog. When the job finishes dismiss the progress dialog and start Activity A.
Or you can check a flag in onCreate in Activity A to know if it need to show progressDialog and when the service sendBroadcast dismiss the progressDialog.